# Javascript - выполнение операций в фоновом режиме

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю HTML страницу, нужно сделать так, чтобы продолжительные операции (типа http-запроса) выполнялись в фоновом режиме и не заставляли интерфейс подвисать.
Например, выполнить такой код:

```
            var xhr = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

            var client = new xhr();

            client.open('GET', url, false);

            client.send();
```

чтобы при этом графический интерфейс не зависал до тех пор, пока операция не выполнится?

Comment: Вы сами у себя вопрос спрашиваете? В целом, ответ кроется в волшебном слове Async, которое достаточно подробно описано в XMLHttpRequest

Comment: И в вашем случае: client.open('GET', url, false); - это слово равно "false"

Comment: у Вас выполняется синхронный запрос, который и "блокирует" любой другой сценарий, посмотрите как указывали выше - асинхронный тип запросов

Answer (score 3):

Нут так и запускайте в асинхронном режиме

```
var xhr = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;
var client = new xhr();
client.open('GET', url, true);
// Определяем обработчик
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4) {
    // Обработка результатов
  }
};
client.send();
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте promise, например:

```
function httpGet(url) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);

        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                resolve(this.response);
            } else {
                var error = new Error(this.statusText);
                error.code = this.status;
                reject(error);
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function() {
            reject(new Error("Network Error"));
        };

        xhr.send();
    });
}

httpGet("someURL")
    .then(
        response => alert(`Fulfilled: ${response}`),
        error => alert(`Rejected: ${error}`)
    );
```